# FB.login gives wrong userID

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's been a couple of months since I last used the Facebook API and I noticed some stuff is not working like it used to:
In my old (javascript) code I assumed that when the response status was 'connected' the response.authResponse.userID would be the actual fb-userid but for some reason I get a totally different id which I can quite place. This always worked perfectly so the code itself should be correct but I assume they messed with the api (again).

My (test)user id is: 100004759963992
but when I login response.authResponse.userID appears to be: 289197071248956

Any thoughts on what this id represents or how to get the correct user id (whithout making an additional call)?

P.S. The api documentation is such a mess that I couldn't find any info on the authResponse.userID

Comment: You are getting the app scoped user id back. That is by design and there is no way to get the real user id.

Why do you even need the real user id?

Comment: Thanks! In hindsight the id wasn't used anymore in my code. But good to know what the other userID means. Would have been more clear if they had given it a different name to prevent confusion.

Comment: It would have broken so many things if we changed the name. And no one should really rely on the user id being the real user id anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App-scoped user IDs were introduced in Graph API v2.0. In short, they remain the same within the application but are not global, i.e. cannot be used from another app (unless you map them accross business applications.) Read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading).